# Django/Daphne, got NotImplementedError calling asyncio.create_subprocess_exec( under WINDOWS

Tags: python, django, daphne

I am using Django 3.2 with Daphne 3.0.2, Python 3.8.9 under Windows 10.

Trying to call

```
proc = await asyncio.create_subprocess_exec(
        python_exe,
        bridge_script,
        stdin=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE,
        stdout=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr=asyncio.subprocess.STDOUT,
        )
```

Gives me following error:

```
Exception Type: NotImplementedError
Exception Location: c:\python\python38\lib\asyncio\base_events.py, line 491, in _make_subprocess_transport
```

When serving Django/ASGI with daphne.
Under Linux everything runs fine.
Serving under Windows with Python runserver also everything fine, Just daphne & windows gives me the error.

Thanks for any help.